# Using ParseSQL Command for ADO Parameters Cause Invalid Parameter DataType

Tags: sql, delphi, ado, delphi-xe4, tadoquery

I have some SQL Command that contains a parameter such:(Note that myID has "int" type in SQL)

> vSqlString :='Select * From myTable Where myID= :paramID';

and Use ParseSQL Command to execute this command:

> myADOQuery.Parameters.ParseSQL(vSqlString , True);

Now myADOQuery.Parameters.ParamByName('paramID').DataType is smallint Type and it can't accept negative integer values.

I can exactly show to compiler that my Parameter[0].DataType is ftIneteger and it works properly, but what is a good solution for this problem?

Comment: Have you tried changing the datatype: `myADOQuery.Parameters.ParamByName('paramID').DataType := ftInteger;`

Comment: Alternatively you can set up the parameters manually rather than by calling ParseSQL.

Comment: @Keith Miller: yes. i do and it works properly. but if i change my parameters or t-sql objects, i must change this line and it seems not good. i want a solution to tell me how can i don't define my parameters type and complier recognize them

Comment: what is your DB backend? Smallint type is rather weird for an identity column?

Comment: @whosrdaddy : this Question is a sample of parameters and paramID might be non identity column. in this sample myID has "int" type in SQL and i get small int for it! I want to pass a negative value to this parameter.

Comment: @MohammadGohari I think that is the best solution. The compiler cannot query the DB to see what the column datatypes are so you have to tell it. Personally I don't use ParseSQL, I set up the parameters in code so I have full control.

Comment: How did you conclude that the parameter type is smallint?  If you place ShowMessage ( inttostr ( ord ( myADOQuery.Parameters.ParamByName('paramID').DataType ) ) ) after the call to ParseSQL what is the result?  My hypothesis is that it is zero indicating ftUnknown.

Comment: You don't say what the DB is. Looking at your query I would guess that that it is Oracle by the ':' in the parameter name. In SQL Server it should be '@'.

Comment: see this article
[ADOQuery.ParseSql][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21194122/tadoquery-parsesql-do-not-work-in-xe4?noredirect=1#comment31943496_21194122

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My question is asked by [Mr. imanShadabi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2858648/imanshadabi) Here: [Using TAdoQuery.ParseSql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21194122/tadoquery-parsesql-do-not-work-in-xe4) and has resolved  by [user1008646](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1008646/user1008646)

Comment: Glad I could help.  I wonder how I'd go about collecting the bounty.

Comment: @user1008646, don't worry. You'll get one :-)

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help.

If you want to create in runtime parameters, you can use something like this:

```
ADOQuery1.Close;
ADOQuery1.SQL.Text := vSqlString;
ADOQuery1.Parameters.Clear;
ADOQuery1.Parameters.CreateParameter('paramID', ftInteger, pdInput, 10, vIntegerValue);
ADOQuery1.Open;
```

Or you can concatenate values to the query. 
For example:

```
//For Integer values:
vSqlString: = 'Select * From myTable Where myID =' + IntToStr (vIntegerValue); 

//For String values:
vSqlString: = 'Select * From myTable Where myID =' + QuotedStr (vStringValue); 

//For float values: 
//Be careful with this, usually in a query, the comma is separator values, 
//so make sure that the decimal separator is '.'
vDS := DecimalSeparator; //I keep the value it had 
DecimalSeparator := '.'; 
try
  ADOQuery1.close;
  ADOQuery1.SQL.Text := 'Select * From myTable Where myID='+FloatToStr(vFloatValue);
  ADOQuery1.Open;
finally
  DecimalSeparator := vDS; //Restore the value that had
end;
```

The third option is to set the parameters at design time. 
But I think this is not what you want.

Comment: thanks aljarafe. but I wanna use ParseSQL and know this command bug