# TAdoQuery.ParseSql do not work in xe4

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, ado, delphi-xe4

I have a project in Delphi 7 and I use `TAdoQuery.ParseSql();` to load parameters. Now I compile it in XE4 and type of parameters is sometimes wrong. It's really `ftInteger` but created as `ftSmallint`. What can I do to solve this problem? My DB is SQL Server 2008 R2.

Table definition:

```sql
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblTest]( 
   [sysId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,  
   [Code] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL, 
   [Name] [nvarchar](500) NOT NULL, 
CONSTRAINT [PK_tblTest] 
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ( [sysId] ASC )
   WITH ( PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, 
          ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON ) 
   ON [PRIMARY] )
ON [PRIMARY]
```

Sample data:

```sql
INSERT INTO tblTest ( Code, Name ) VALUES ( 'a1', 'name1' )
```

Delphi code:

```
ADOQuery.SQL.Text := 'SELECT * FROM tblTest WHERE sysId = :sysId';
AdoQuery.Parameters.ParseSQL(ADOQuery.SQL.Text,True);
AdoQuery.Parameters.ParamByName('sysId').value := -1;
AdoQuery.open;
```

`ConnectionString` (database: `MyDb`)

```
Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;Initial  Catalog=MyDb;Data Source=.
```

as a solution i use this delphi code

```
AdoQuery.Parameters.ParseSQL(ADOQuery.SQL.Text,false);
```

And now can any body Explain this? is there any side effect?

Comment: What version of SQL Server? What does the SQL code look like. Do you use mdac or sqlncli to connect to the db?

Comment: duplicate without answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20813585/using-parsesql-command-for-ado-parameters-cause-invalid-parameter-datatype

Comment: @Mikael the version is sqlserver2008R2 and use MDAC to connect

Comment: Emphasize that it worked in delphi7

Comment: I'd be curious to see the code that comes after ParseSQL that indicates the parameter datatype, and indicates that it "works" in Delphi 7.   When you assign SQL.Text, if the AdoQuery.Connection is set, your app will query the SQL Server for the type.  At this point the type should be ftInteger.  When you call ParseSQL with DoCreate=true, the parameter list will be deleted, and new parameters will be created, but with DataType=ftUnknown.  I've tested this in Delphi 7 and Delphi XE5. (sorry, don't have XE4).

Comment: @user1008646 I edit Delphi Code; i understand that as a solution can use AdoQuery.Parameters.ParseSQL(ADOQuery.SQL.Text,false); instead of AdoQuery.Parameters.ParseSQL(ADOQuery.SQL.Text,true);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, before I get into any explanation about ParseSQL, check your connection string.  There are two spaces between Initial and Catalog.  When I used that connection string I got an error opening the query that tblTest does not exist.  Removing the extra space resolved that problem.

When I saw this question I had no idea what ParseSQL does. I've been doing Delphi / SQL Server / ADO development for years and never used it.  I thought this would be an opportunity to learn something new.

Please note that all the tests I ran gave identical results in Delphi 7 and Delphi XE5.  I'd still be curious to see some code that works in Delphi 7 but doesn't work in Delphi XE5.

When you execute  `AdoQuery.SQL.Text:='...'`, if the connection is set and open, your application will create the parameters, and query the database server to determine their types. This code:

```
AdoQuery := tAdoQuery . Create(nil);
AdoQuery . Connection := AdoConnection;
ADOQuery.SQL.Text := 'SELECT * FROM tblTest WHERE sysId = :sysId';

aDataType := AdoQuery.Parameters.ParamByName ( 'sysId' ) . DataType;
Msg ( 'Parameter type = ' + DataTypeToString ( aDataType ) );
```

will result in:

```
Parameter type = ftInteger
```

Note, DataTypeToString is just a routine I wrote to convert tDataType to string.

```
function DataTypeToString ( const nDataType : tDataType ) : string;
begin
  Result := GetEnumName ( TypeInfo(tDataType),
                          integer (nDataType) );
end;
```

Then execute this code.

```
AdoQuery.Parameters.ParamByName ( 'sysId' ) . Value := -1;
AdoQuery . Open;
```

If you run SQL Profiler you'll see what query is sent to the SQL Server:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT * FROM tblTest WHERE sysId = @P1
',N'@P1 int',-1
```

Note that @P1 is declared as `int`.

*Note:  If you have two spaces in the connection string, the parameter type will be shown as `ftUnknown`, and @P1 will be type `smallint`.  The remainder of this answer will assume you have the correct connection string with one space.*

What does calling `ParseSQL` with `DoCreate=true` do?

```
AdoQuery.Parameters.ParseSQL(ADOQuery.SQL.Text,True);
```

The first thing it does is clear the parameter list.  In this case, that means the correctly typed parameter we already had is destroyed.  `ParseSQL` then parses the SQL and finds the parameter.  It creates a new `tParameter` object with name `sysID` and adds it to the list.  The new parameter has type `ftUnknown`.

Why would anyone want to do this?  If the query connection was NOT set, or was not OPEN, this could be very useful. The parameter list would be built for you, after which you could explicitly set their datatypes.

What if instead you were to execute `ParseSQL` with `DoCreate=false`:

```
AdoQuery.Parameters.ParseSQL(ADOQuery.SQL.Text,false);
```

The answer is:  nothing.  ParseSQL will parse the SQL, find the parameters, and it will return a string like this:

```
SELECT * FROM tblTest WHERE sysId = ?
```

replacing the parameter with a question mark. It will make no changes the to the parameter list.  Since your code does nothing with the returned string, the net result is that this call to ParseSQL makes no changes.